# Issue with memory allocation in beginner OpenCL code

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to run a beginner level OpenCL test using an Intel CPU and integrated Iris graphics. I am compiling the code using the standard g++ and `-framework OpenCL` as a compile switch. I've tried sanitizing the code by running with gdb and referring a few guides online. But, I'm still seeing an error and I am supposing this is related to memory allocation. I have pasted my entire code below; please help if you see anything glaringly wrong.

Apologies for the verbose comments. Let me know if I have some wrong assumptions there as well :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#include <cassert>
    
// the kernel that we want to execute on the device.
// here, you are doing an addition of elements in an array.
const char* kernelAdd =
{
    "__kernel void add (global int* data)\n"
    "{\n" 
    "   int work_item_id = get_global_id(0);\n"
    "   data[work_item_id] *= 2;\n"
    "}\n"
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cl_int ret_val;

    // getting the platform ID that can used - here we are getting only one
    cl_platform_id platformID;
    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    if((clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platformID, &numPlatforms)))
        std::cout << "clGetPlatformIDs failed!" << std::endl;

    // getting OpenCL device ID for our GPU - here too, we are getting only one
    cl_device_id deviceID;
    cl_uint numDevices;
    if((clGetDeviceIDs(platformID, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &deviceID, &numDevices)))
        std::cout << "clGetDeviceIDs failed!" << std::endl;

    // printing out some device info. here we have chosen CL_DEVICE_NAME.
    // you can choose any others by referring
    // https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html
    typedef char typeInfo;
    size_t sizeInfo = 16*sizeof(typeInfo);
    typeInfo* deviceInfo = new typeInfo(sizeInfo); 
    if((clGetDeviceInfo(deviceID, CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeInfo, (void*) deviceInfo, NULL)))
        std::cout << "clGetDeviceInfo failed!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "CL_DEVICE_NAME = " << deviceInfo << ", platform ID = ";
    std::cout << platformID << ", deviceID = " << deviceID << std::endl;
    
    // set up a context for our device
    cl_context_properties contextProp[3] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) platformID, 0};
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(contextProp, 1, &deviceID, NULL, NULL, &ret_val);
    if (ret_val)
        std::cout << "clCreateContext failed!" << std::endl;

    // set up a queue for our device
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceID, (cl_command_queue_properties) NULL, &ret_val);
    if (ret_val)
        std::cout << "clCreateCommandQueue failed!" << std::endl;

    // creating our data set that we want to compute on
    int N = 1 << 4;
    size_t data_size = sizeof(int) * N;
    int* input_data = new int(N);
    int* output_data = new int(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    {
        input_data[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }

    // create a buffer to where you will eventually enqueue the program for the device
    cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, data_size, NULL, &ret_val);
    if (ret_val)
        std::cout << "clCreateBuffer failed!" << std::endl;

    // copying our data set to the buffer
    if((clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, data_size, input_data, 0, NULL, NULL)))
        std::cout << "clEnqueueWriteBuffer failed!" << std::endl;

    // we compile the device program with our source above and create a kernel for it.
    // also, we are allowed to create a device program with a binary that we can point to.
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**) &kernelAdd, NULL, &ret_val); 
    if (ret_val)
        std::cout << "clCreateProgramWithSource failed!" << std::endl; 

    if((clBuildProgram(program, 1, &deviceID, NULL, NULL, NULL)))
        std::cout << "clBuildProgram failed!" << std::endl; 

    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "add", &ret_val);
    if (ret_val)
        std::cout << "clCreateKernel failed! ret_val = " << ret_val << std::endl;

    // configure options to find the arguments to the kernel
    if((clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(buffer), &buffer)))
        std::cout << "clSetKernelArg failed!" << std::endl;

    // the total number of work items that we want to use
    const size_t global_dimensions[3] = {data_size, 0, 0};
    if((clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_dimensions, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)))
        std::cout << "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed!" << std::endl;

    // read back output into another buffer
    ret_val = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, data_size, output_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret_val)
        std::cout << "clEnqueueReadBuffer failed! ret_val = " << ret_val << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Kernel completed" << std::endl;

    // Release kernel, program, and memory objects
    if(clReleaseMemObject(buffer))
        std::cout << "clReleaseMemObject failed!" << std::endl;

    if(clReleaseKernel(kernel))
        std::cout << "clReleaseKernel failed!" << std::endl;

    if(clReleaseProgram(program))
        std::cout << "clReleaseProgram failed!" << std::endl;

    if(clReleaseCommandQueue(queue))
        std::cout << "clReleaseCommandQueue failed!" << std::endl;

    if(clReleaseContext(context))
        std::cout << "clReleaseContext failed!" << std::endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    {
        assert(output_data[i] == input_data[i]/2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
CL_DEVICE_NAME = Iris, platform ID = 0x7fff0000, deviceID = 0x1024500
objc[1034]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
objc[1034]: receiver 0x7fefb8712a90, SEL 0x7fff7ce87c58, isa 0x7fff99268208, cache 0x7fff99268218, buckets 0x7fefb87043c0, mask 0x3, occupied 0x1
objc[1034]: receiver 48 bytes, buckets 64 bytes
objc[1034]: selector 'dealloc'
objc[1034]: isa 'OS_xpc_array'
objc[1034]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
make: *** [all] Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a common mistake

```
int* input_data = new int(N);
```

should be

```
int* input_data = new int[N];
```

Your version allocates a single `int` and initialises it to `N`. To allocate `N` integers you need square brackets.

Comment: Thanks! Little embarrassing that I missed that! I've corrected it but I am seeing a similar failure.

The errors are not consistent. In some cases, it proceeds to the end of the program to fail at the assertion. In some cases, it fails as below:

opencl_basic.app(1475,0x11bbebdc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object
0x7ff724704688: probably modified after being freed.

Corrupt value: 0x26400000348
opencl_basic.app(1475,0x11bbebdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
make: *** [all] Abort trap: 6

Comment: @pigbabez OK well the second error is that since you are using `data_size` integers, you need to allocate `data_size` integers `int* input_data = new int[data_size]; int* output_data = new int[data_size];`. Or maybe you got your loop wrong and you only meant to use `N` integers `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`. Either way you must be consistent.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed that but the error remains and I suppose it has something to with the OpenCL buffer allocation.

Comment: @pigbabez Maybe I wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: You were right! Apologies for the previous comment: I was using data_size instead of N in the assert loop as well. Changing that to N fixed it! Thank you.